# How Postgres achieves database-level isolation

Tags: postgresql

Per doc of [postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/manage-ag-overview.html),

> Databases are physically separated and access control is managed at the connection level.

Is there any further details that how Postgres achieves this physical isolation? Are those files used to store data in the backend totally separate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any further details that how postgres archives this physical isolation? Are those files used to store data in the backend totally separate?

Yes. Each table is stored as a separate file (actually, multiple files). Different databases are in different directories. Indexes, etc are also in one or more separate files.

However, there's a *lot* of shared state. Some system tables are shared between all databases. The write-ahead log (WAL) is also shared, as is the commit log (`pg_clog`). So you *cannot* just extract one database's files and attach it to another PostgreSQL instance. They're meaningless without some of the shared files.